# How to plot stacked proportional graph?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dataframe, stacked

I have a data frame:

```
x <- data.frame(id=letters[1:3],val0=1:3,val1=4:6,val2=7:9)
  id val0 val1 val2
1  a    1    4    7
2  b    2    5    8
3  c    3    6    9
```

I want to plot a stacked bar plot that shows the percentage of each columns. So, each bar represents one row and and each bar is of length but of three different colors each color representing percentage of val0, val1 and val2.

I tried looking for it, I am getting only ways to plot stacked graph but not stacked proportional graph.

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean each bar should be of same length?

Answer (score 5):

### Using ggplot2

For `ggplot2` and `geom_bar`

1. Work in long format
2. Pre-calculate the  percentages

For example

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
# long format with column of proportions within each id
xlong <- ddply(melt(x, id.vars = 'id'), .(id), mutate, prop = value / sum(value))

ggplot(xlong, aes(x = id, y = prop, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

```
 # note position = 'fill' would work with the value column
 ggplot(xlong, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = variable)) +
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'fill', aes(fill = variable))
```

### # will return the same plot as above

### base R

A table object can be plotted as a mosaic plot. using `plot`. Your `x` is (almost) a table object

```
# get the numeric columns as a matrix
xt <- as.matrix(x[,2:4])
# set the rownames to be the first column of x
rownames(xt) <- x[[1]]
# set the class to be a table so plot will call plot.table
class(xt) <- 'table'
plot(xt)
```

[image]

you could also use `mosaicplot` directly

```
mosaicplot(x[,2:4], main = 'Proportions')
```

Comment: Thanks. How do we change the width of the columns?? I have a lot of columns so, the column width are very small. Also how do we change the orientation of the X-axis labels.?

Comment: Note that `geom_bar()` accepts the argument `position="fill"` which would allow you to skip the `ddply` step and use the melted data.frame directly.