# How to plot a diagram like this in matplot/python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got a dictionary like this and want to visualize the online times of a certain streamer.

```
{1: ['2018-09-20 20:40:50', '2018-09-20 21:11:14'], 2: ['2018-09-20 12:45:44', '2018-09-20 13:22:24']}
```

I made a fancy draw to show you what kind of diagram i need.

[image: diagram]

Since im totally beginner to python, i cannot figure out how to plot this with matplot. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you define what are what ? what is the red line? Label things on the plot? Also show what approaches did you try ?

Comment: This kind of plot is usually called Gantt-chart. This notion might help you find existing solutions to your problem.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820578/how-to-plot-stacked-event-duration-gantt-charts-using-python-pandas

The difference in your case that you also potentially want to group by date first

Answer (score 0):

What you want to plot seems to be something like a Gantt Chart.
You can see a great example about plotting Gantt Charts with matplot on [this link](https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2016/05/10/quick-gantt-chart-with-matplotlib/)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. The trick with a Gantt chart is to compute the offset between the origin and the time you want it to occur. See below for the code with some comments.

```
import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = {1: ['2018-09-20 20:40:50', '2018-09-20 21:11:14'], \
 2: ['2018-09-20 12:45:44', '2018-09-20 13:22:24']}

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # open figure; create axis
ylabels = [] # extract the dates
yticks  = [] # track the position on the y-axis
for k, v in data.items():
    # extract the time > see python docs for meaning of the symbols
    times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for i in v] 
    offset= times[0].hour # offset from the left
    delta = times[1].hour - times[0].hour # compute stream time
    ax.barh(k, delta, left = offset, align = 'center') # plot
    ylabels.append(v[0].split(' ')[0]) # extract date
    yticks.append(k)
# format figure
ax.set(**dict(xlabel = 'Time[hour]', xlim = (0, 24), \
              yticks = yticks, yticklabels = ylabels))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/) has interactive Gantt charts out of the box if you are not limited to Matplotlib only.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

df = [dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
      dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
      dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')]

fig = ff.create_gantt(df)
py.iplot(fig, filename='gantt-simple-gantt-chart', world_readable=True)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeCOH.png)