# Gantt Chart from dictionary with lists of discrete non-contiguous dates as values

Tags: python, dictionary, plotly, data-visualization, gantt-chart

I'm trying to build a Gantt chart in Python (indifferent to package used... perhaps Plotly?) where the X-axis will be discrete dates (e.g., 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02, ...) and the Y-axis will be names (e.g., 'A', 'B', ...). The lists of dates per name aren't necessarily contiguous. They are currently in the following format:

```
names_dict = {
              'A': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-31'], 
              'B': ['2020-01-03'], 
              'C': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'],
              ...
              }
```

Is there an easy way to build a Gantt-type chart from a dictionary in this format? Ideally it would be a grid, and for each date on the X-axis the square for a given name would either be white or red (indicating the presence of that date in the list of dates for that name). Thus, the dates on the X-axis would be the continuous range from the earliest date present in any list in the dictionary to the latest date.

Comment: Quite some ideas in the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432281/how-to-plot-a-diagram-like-this-in-matplot-python/). There is also [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803727/how-to-get-gantt-plot-using-matplotlib-for-task-with-start-time-and-end-time-upt) and [this article](https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2016/05/10/quick-gantt-chart-with-matplotlib/).

Comment: @JohanC these seem to refer to continuous Gantt charts (with a single start date and end date per row) -- any ideas on how to make a discontinuous one?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the given data with matplotlib's horizontal bars (`barh`). The dictionary is traversed in reverse order of the keys, as matplotlib draws them starting at the bottom.

Matplotlib allows a myriad of tweeking, for every aspect of the plot.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

names_dict = {'A': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-31'],
              'B': ['2020-01-03'],
              'C': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'] }

# x_min = min([datetime.fromisoformat(d) for dates in names_dict.values() for d in dates])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
for name in reversed(list(names_dict.keys())):
    for d in names_dict[name]:
        ax.barh(name, width=1.0, left=mdates.date2num(datetime.fromisoformat(d)),
                height=1.0, color='crimson', align='center')
for i in range(len(names_dict)+1):
    ax.axhline(i-0.5, color='black')

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b %d"))
# ax.grid(True, axis='x') # to show vertical gridlines at each major tick
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question?