# How to get a gannt chart using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following data:

[data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQcWe.png)

I want to create a gannt chart that would represent a timeline in python. I looked up another post that had a similar problem but the code didn't work out for me ([How to get gantt plot using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367690/how-to-get-gantt-plot-using-matplotlib)) and I can't solve the issue on my own. It seems like it has something to do with the data type of my "time" values. Here is the code itself:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('zpp00141_new.csv')
df.dropna(subset=['Latest finish / time', 'Earl. start / time'])
#error when I try to change data type of the columns to int
df["Latest finish / time"]= df["Latest finish / time"].astype(int) 
df["Earl. start / time"]= df["Earl. start / time"].astype(int)
#error below with data types
df["Diff"] = df['Latest finish / time'] - df['Earl. start / time']
color = {"In":"turquoise", "Out":"crimson"}
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,3))

labels=[]
for i, task in enumerate(df.groupby("Operation/Activity")):
    labels.append(task[0])
    for r in task[1].groupby("Operation short text"):
        data = r[1][["Earl. start / time", "Diff"]]
        ax.broken_barh(data.values, (i-0.4,0.8), color=color[r[0]] )

ax.set_yticks(range(len(labels)))
ax.set_yticklabels(labels) 
ax.set_xlabel("time [ms]")
plt.tight_layout()       
plt.show()
```

I tried to convert data type from object to "int" for the columns but it prompted another error: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '9:22:00 AM'". I would really appreciate any assistance in this matter as I am quite new to programming in python. If there is a simpler and better way to represent what I need, it would be helpful if you could provide any tips. Basically, I need a gannt chart to represent each activity on the "timeline" from 7 am to 4:30 pm and reflect "now" time as a vertical line over the chart to indicate where we are now.

Comment: Maybe [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654501/gantt-chart-from-dictionary-with-lists-of-discrete-non-contiguous-dates-as-value/59665560#59665560) can help?

Comment: Thanks for providing this example but my times are in a different format: h:min:sec AM/PM. And I need the graph to show the timeline from 7 am to 4:30 pm with hourly intervals. As a data input, I use csv file with start time and end time categorized by certain operation/activity. If you don't mind telling, how would I modify the code for these requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the time strings are not in a standard format, `datetime.strptime` can be used to convert them. `strptime` needs everything to be zero padded, so the code below checks whether the string starts with 1 or 2 digits and prepends a zero if needed.

Here is an example to get you started. I didn't grasp the code in the question, as some columns seem to be missing. Also, I changed the names of the columns to be compatible with variable names to be able to use `row.start` instead of `row[1]`.

Colors can be assigned to each operation, just be creating a list of them. Matoplotlib has some [built-in colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) that can be used. For example, 'tab10' has 10 different colors. The list can be repeated if there aren't enough colors for each individual opereration.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
import math

def timestr_to_num(timestr):
    return mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime('0' + timestr if timestr[1] == ':' else timestr, '%I:%M:%S %p'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['7:00:00 AM', '1:00:00 PM', '7:20:00 AM', '2:00:00 PM'],
                   'finish': ['12:15:00 PM', '4:20:00 PM', '1:10:00 PM', '3:30:00 PM'],
                   'operation': ['operation 1', 'operation 1', 'operation 2', 'operation 3'],
                   'short_text': ['short text 1', 'short text 2', 'short text 1', 'short text 2']})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 3))
operations = pd.unique(df['operation'])
colors = plt.cm.tab10.colors  # get a list of 10 colors
colors *= math.ceil(len(operations) / (len(colors)))  # repeat the list as many times as needed
for operation, color in zip(operations, colors):
    for row in df[df['operation'] == operation].itertuples():
        left = timestr_to_num(row.start)
        right = timestr_to_num(row.finish)
        ax.barh(operation, left=left, width=right - left, height=0.8, color=color)
ax.set_xlim(timestr_to_num('07:00:00 AM'), timestr_to_num('4:30:00 PM'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))  # display ticks as hours and minutes
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))  # set a tick every hour
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks for the code but what if I don't have the "In/out" column in my data. I only have the times. How do I assign the colors in that case? I would like to see each operation have a different color but I don't want to specify the color for each operation manually, I would prefer the color to be randomly picked or be the same across all the operations. What would be different in a code in that case?

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to plot a gantt chart with your help!

Comment: Could you by any chance advice on how to plot a vertical red line that would correspond with the current time on x-axis? I tried using plt.axvline but I can't figure out how to convert it to make it work with my formatting and data. Thanks a lot in advance!