# Plotting duration on a timeline in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I'd like to plot the sequential spans of different people vertically on a shared (temporal) x-axis. My data looks like this:

```
    Name                start       end
0   John Rutledge   1790-02-15  1791-03-05
1   William Cushing 1790-02-02  1810-09-13
2   James Wilson    1789-10-05  1798-08-21
3   John Blair      1790-02-02  1795-10-25
4   James Iredell   1790-05-12  1799-10-20
```

Desired output is something like this:

[image]

I've seen some fairly complex 'roll-your-own' versions of this, but isn't there something simple?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820578/how-to-plot-stacked-event-duration-gantt-charts-using-python-pandas

Comment: `broken_barh` would be pretty simple, I'd say.