# how to generate subplots using matplotlib hlines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a Gantt chart like visualization  for the below dataset

[Sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPs1I.jpg)

I was able to get it for one date like below

```
df1 = df[df.Date1=='2018-01-01']

ax = plt.hlines(df1.process, df1.start1, df1.end1 )
```

[hlines visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooyXD.jpg)

is there a way to generate subplots for all the dates?

i am looking for something like this

[need something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epYTr.png)

thanks

Comment: if you are ok to use other than matplotlib then use [plotty](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot stacked event duration (Gantt Charts) using Python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820578/how-to-plot-stacked-event-duration-gantt-charts-using-python-pandas)

Comment: i am looking for subplots like attached screen shot(edited my question), i generated that using R but i am trying to create it in python