# Plot a multiple line chart based on date ranges (min and max)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, charts

I have a df like the following:

```
   DATE_MIN DATE_MAX
214 1994-06-29  2010-07-12
125 1969-10-26  2011-10-10
123 2013-07-02  2015-01-29
74  2006-01-05  2016-06-20
```

Columns are: DATE_MIN, DATE_MAX

I would like to plot a long vertical chart with as many horizontal
   lines as df rows.

- With date range in x axis
- With index in y axis,
  hence each line is horizontal, they don't cross each other.

So I want to show which rows have some time overlapping because the lines would have overlapping area (not crossing).

Super thanks in advance!

Comment: Aren't you actually asking for a gantt?

Comment: @rpanai it seems that the closest chart in matplotlib is 'hlines', it worked good enough to me, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot stacked event duration (Gantt Charts) using Python Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820578/how-to-plot-stacked-event-duration-gantt-charts-using-python-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to make a gantt and use plotly you could use this [doc](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/)

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

txt="""TASK  DATE_MIN DATE_MAX
214 1994-06-29  2010-07-12
125 1969-10-26  2011-10-10
123 2013-07-02  2015-01-29
74  2006-01-05  2016-06-20
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)

data = []
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    data.append(dict(Task=str(row["TASK"]),
                     Start=str(row["DATE_MIN"]),
                     Finish=str(row["DATE_MAX"])))

fig = ff.create_gantt(data)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, I wanted to do it without more external libs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the super quick answers so far.
I actually found a good solution for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820578/how-to-plot-stacked-event-duration-gantt-charts-using-python-pandas)

My code hence looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dt

df = df.sort_values(by=['DATE_MIN', 'DATE_MAX'])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 50))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax = ax.xaxis_date()
ax = plt.hlines(df.ID, 
                dt.date2num(df.DATE_MIN), 
                dt.date2num(df.DATE_MAX))
```

Comment: In this case you should flag your question as duplicate.